# Clojure rearrangement and mapping of vector of vectors

Tags: vector, clojure

Here is the situation: I have a vector of vectors ("data"), a set of headers, a subset of headers ("primary headers"), a constant ("C"), an element-wise function ("f"), and the remaining headers ("secondary headers"). My goal is to take the "data" and produce a new vector of vectors.

Example data:

```
[[1.0 "A" 2.0]
[1.0 "B" 4.0]]
```

Example headers:

```
["o1" "i1" "i2"]
```

Example primary headers:

```
 ["i1" "i2"]
```

Example secondary headers:

```
 ["o1"]
```

Example new vector of vectors:

```
[[(f "A") (f 2.0) C (f 1.0)]
[(f "B") (f 4.0) C (f 1.0)]]
```

My current attempt is to mapv each row, then map-indexed each element with an if to check for primary membership, then the constant, then map-indexed each element with an if to check for secondary membership, finally conj on the results. But I am not getting it to work right.

Example code:

```
(mapv (fn [row] (conj (vec (flatten (map-indexed
                                    (fn [idx item] (let [header-name (nth headers idx)] 
                                                        (if (= (some #{header-name} primary-headers) headers-name) (f item))))
                                    row)))

                  C
                  (vec (flatten (map-indexed
                                    (fn [idx item] (let [header-name (nth headers idx)] 
                                                        (if (= (some #{header-name} secondary-headers) headers-name) (f item))))
                                    row)))))
 data)
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the code you have thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got your problem right, but looks like you want something like this:

```
(defn magic [data h p s f]
  (let [idx (map (into {} (map-indexed #(vector %2 %1) h))
                 (concat p s))]
    (mapv #(mapv (comp f (partial get %))
                 idx)
          data)))
```

Here is an example of my `magic` function:

```
(magic [[1.0 "A" 2.0]
        [1.0 "B" 4.0]]
       ["o1" "i1" "i2"]
       ["i1" "i2"]
       ["o1"]
       #(str "<" % ">"))

[["<A>" "<2.0>" "<1.0>"]
 ["<B>" "<4.0>" "<1.0>"]]
```

Let's get a closer look at it.

First of all, I'm calculating permutation index `idx`. In your case it's `(1 2 0)`. In order to calculate it I'm turning `["o1" "i1" "i2"]` into a hash map `{"o1" 0, "i1" 1, "i2" 2}` and then using it on `("i1" "i2" "o1")` sequence of primary and secondary headers.

Then I'm using `idx` to rearrange `data` matrix. On this step I'm also applying `f` function to each element of new rearranged matrix.

## Update

I thought that it'll be best to split my complicated `magic` function into three simpler ones:

```
(defn getPermutation [h1 h2]
  (map (into {} (map-indexed #(vector %2 %1) h1))
       h2))

(defn permutate [idx data]
  (mapv #(mapv (partial get %) idx)
        data)))

(defn mmap [f data]
  (mapv (partial mapv f)
        data))
```

Each function here is atomic (i.e. performing a single task), and they all could be easily combined to do exactly what `magic` function do:

```
(defn magic [data h p s f]
  (let [idx (getPermutation h (concat p s))]
    (->> data
         (permutate idx)
         (mmap f))))
```

`getPermutation` function here calculates `idx` permutation index vector.

`permutate` rearranges columns of a matrix `data` according to given `idx` vector.

`mmap` applies function `f` to each element of a matrix `data`.

## Update 2

Last time I missed the part about adding a constant. So, in order to do so we'll need to change some of the code. Let's change `permutate` function allowing it to insert new values to the matrix.

```
(defn permutate [idx data & [default-val]]
  (mapv #(mapv (partial get %) idx (repeat default-val))
        data)))
```

Now, it'll use `default-val` if it won't be able to get the element with the specified index `idx`.

We'll also need a new `magic` function:

```
(defn magic2 [data h p s f c]
  (let [idx (getPermutation h (concat p [nil] s))]
    (permutate idx (mmap f data) c)))
```

I changed the order of applying `mmap` and `permutate` functions because it seems that you don't want to apply `f` to your constant.

And it works:

```
(magic2 [[1.0 "A" 2.0]
         [1.0 "B" 4.0]]
        ["o1" "i1" "i2"]
        ["i1" "i2"]
        ["o1"]
        #(str "<" % ">")
        "-->")

[["<A>" "<2.0>" "-->" "<1.0>"]
 ["<B>" "<4.0>" "-->" "<1.0>"]]
```

Comment: I still need to test this out, but where does the constant C get added in, between p and s? I'm excited if this works, it uses functions I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Looks like I missed the part about a constant.

Comment: @user1559027 I updated my answer wit the art about adding a constant.

Comment: I am so close to getting your solution working. My only trouble is that permutate is only returning the default value, despite getPermutation and mmap working correctly.

Comment: I marked this comment as the answer. It was the first one I got to work, after quite a bit of modification. You and @Thumbnail were both very educational. There were some extra steps I had to accommodate when passing `f` and in processing the results, but I worked those out.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using [core.matrix](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix) for stuff like this. It is a very flexible tool for multi-dimensional array programming in Clojure.

Most array-manipulation operations are likely to be 1-2 liners.....

```
(def DATA [[1.0 "A" 2.0]
           [1.0 "B" 4.0]])

(emap (partial str "f:") (transpose (mapv #(get-column DATA %) [1 0 2])))
=> [["f:A" "f:1.0" "f:2.0"] 
    ["f:B" "f:1.0" "f:4.0"]]
```

You might need to look up the column names to calculate the `[1 0 2]` vector but hopefully this gives you a good idea how to do this....

Comment: I've been thinking that I need a data structure to help me do these things. Still trying to just make this work for now. Do you think something like Incanter would be useful for all of this?

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
(def data [[1.0 "A" 2.0] [1.0 "B" 4.0]])
(def headers ["o1" "i1" "i2"])
(def primaries ["i1" "i2"])
(def secondaries ["o1"])

(defn invert-sequence [s] (into {} (map-indexed (fn [i x] [x i]) s)))
```

... this does the job:

```
(defn produce [hs ps ss f data const]
  (let [perms (map #(mapv (invert-sequence hs) %) [ps ss])]
    (mapv (fn [v] (->> perms
                       (map #(map (comp f v) %))
                       (interpose [const])
                       (apply concat)
                       vec))
          data)))
```

Using the example in the question:

```
(produce headers primaries secondaries #(list 'f %) data 'C)
; [[(f "A") (f 2.0) C (f 1.0)] [(f "B") (f 4.0) C (f 1.0)]]
```

Using Leonid Beschastny's example:

```
(produce headers primaries secondaries #(str "<" % ">") data 'C)
; [["<A>" "<2.0>" C "<1.0>"] ["<B>" "<4.0>" C "<1.0>"]]
```

Using `str`:

```
(produce headers primaries secondaries str data 'C)
; [["A" "2.0" C "1.0"] ["B" "4.0" C "1.0"]]
```

Using `identity`:

```
(produce headers primaries secondaries identity data 'C)
; [["A" 2.0 C 1.0] ["B" 4.0 C 1.0]]
```

Comment: I've been trying for a while, but I can't get your solution to work. It has the constant, which is great, but it doesn't seem to work with applying the function. Function should be applied to each element. @Leonid-Beschastny has the right idea there.

Comment: @user1559027 What do you get when you run the code?  I copied it back off the page and it works perfectly here, using either version of function `produce`. And the function (`#(list 'f %)` in the example) *is* applied to every element, as the output shows. This example function literally mimics your output - it does nothing useful. Meantime, I'll get rid of the untidy version of `produce`, to reduce the possibilities for confusion.

Comment: I'll try to product something more helpful later, but for now I'm gettgin `clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn`. This is happening when I try to put my true f function directly in the subroutine. Even using "str" or "identity". This is while I am trying to adapt the code into an existing application. What you have may be correct, and it's just me not being able to understand it.

Comment: @user1559027 What's the actual text of your true `f` function? Put it in `code quotes`, to show how far it extends. Both `str` and `identity` work here.

Comment: I will see what I can about getting `f` on here. The problem with `f` is that it requires looking up values in other vectors, which depends on knowing which position (according to `hs`) is being mapped. `map-indexed` was able to help, but I could not figure out the rearrangement of the items.

Comment: `(fn [idx item] (let [header-name (nth hs idx)]
                   (if (= (some #{header-name} divide-headers) header-name)
                     (vector (str (/ item (nth (nth divisors 1) (.indexOf (nth divisors 0) header-name)))))
                     (vec (function-that-returns-a-list)))))`

Comment: `(def divisors [["i2" "o1"][25.0 1000.0]])`

Comment: @user1559027 Your function has two unbound symbols: `hs`, which I take to be my `headers`; and `divide-headers`, which I have no idea about.